# Key not being recognized in JSON

Tags: node.js, json, node-sqlite3

I have following JSON that i am trying to parse.

```
{"id":1,"colour":"blue","count(colour)":1}
```

It is a result of what i have returned from my sqlite3 select staement. I am doing a count(colours), which is being returned as the key in the JSON.
Then when i attempt to reference the value using .count(colour), my node app fails giving me an error that colour is not defined. Note, that referencing .id works just fine.

Has anybody ran into this issue before or can provide any help?

Comment: It seems you are not working with JSON, but with a JavaScript object that is the parsed result of JSON. Otherwise `.id` would not work. If so, please read the tag description of `json`, especially the part in capitals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JSON is in some variable, `myjson`, and you access it directly with `myjson.count(colours)`, you get the error because it's trying to execute a function in your object.

It works as you expect if you access via string like this: `myjson["count(colour)"]`.